# assign html page to a variable

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to assign the contents of a simple html page to a variable?

```
$mail = (require("mail.html"));
```

The purpose is to include text from a web page in an email instead of text from a database.

Comment: [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)?

Comment: I found the same question on this web ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948395/require-include-into-variable

Comment: Many thanks Barmer and others. file_get_contents works great.

Comment: Apuig: Have you marked me down? The accepted answer of the link is entirely different from the one barmer and aWebDeveloper gave which is very neat and what I was after. True, 6 answers down is a post but that was never accept nor commented on. I think this question / answer will be useful to others too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `file_get_contents` to read the contents of a web page:

```
$mail = file_get_contents('mail.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_get_contents()`. You can use this function to get content into a variable

```
$mail = file_get_contents("mail.html");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

or use readfile (not recommneded though)

```
ob_start();
readfile("text.txt");
$data = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 ob_start();
 require_once "mail.html";
 $mail = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

> your requirment needed **file_get_contents()**.try below code:

```
$mail = file_get_contents('mail.html');
```