# php include into a variable then echo that variable

Tags: php, echo, php-include

I want to include a file entirely into a variable. So that I can call this var multiple times and keep the code as clean as possible. But when I echo the var it only returns a `1` and when I use the `include` on itself it output the entire file.

I want to output the included file and run all php code inside it.

So what am I doing wrong here.

## default.php

```
$jpath_eyecatcher = (JURI::base(). "modules/mod_eyecatcher/tmpl/content/eyecatcher.php");
$jpath_eyecatcher_path = parse_url($jpath_eyecatcher, PHP_URL_PATH);
ob_start();
$eyecatcher = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $jpath_eyecatcher_path);
ob_end_clean();


echo $eyecatcher . '<br>';

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $jpath_eyecatcher_path);
```

#### echo output is

1

#### include output is

```
eyecatchertype = 2 
fontawesome
envelope-o
insert_emoticon
custom-icon-class
128
images/clientimages/research (1).jpg
top
test
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: BTW: 1 as output in this case means that include was successfull.

Comment: I didn't know that thanks man.

Comment: Do you want to get the result of script to variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [require/include into variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948395/require-include-into-variable)

Comment: @Don'tPanic I disagree because I have read that post and couldn't get it to work for the simple reason the example code that Jan Willem provided was not present and in my opinion not properly explained

Comment: @splash58 I want to output the full php code and run it when it gets called in the echo.

Comment: Agree to disagree. When I look at that question, I see multiple answers to that contain examples of using output buffering to do this. But you're certainly entitled to your opinion as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `file_get_contents` or `ob_get_clean`, like so:

```
ob_start();
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $jpath_eyecatcher_path);
$eyecatcher = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Thank you very much I tried `file_get_contents` and it didn't output the way I wanted but then did your code with `ob_end_clean` and the output was exactly as I hoped for. So thank you very much I accept this answer as the one that solved my problem.

Answer (score 7):

Use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of `include()`

include() executes the php code given in the file, whereas file_get_contents() gives you the file content.

Comment: Thank you for that information it made me understand now why I can't use the file_get_contents. So maybe my question was a bit unclear sorry about that.

Answer (score 7):

`include` is not a function, and normally only returns the status of the include operation:

[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. **Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1**. It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script which called it. Also, it's possible to return values from included files.

e.g.

x.php:

```
<?php
return 42;
```

y.php

```
<?php
$y = 'foo';
```

z.php

```
<?php
$z = include 'x.php';
echo $z; // outputs 42

$y = include 'y.php';
echo $y; // ouputs 1, for 'true', because the include was successful
         // and the included file did not have a 'return' statement.
```

Also note that `include` will only execute the included code if it contains `<?php ... ?>` code block. Otherwise anything included is simply treated as output.

Comment: You can use `include ('x.php');` as well!

Comment: Thanks for the extensive information I love it when people take the time to be so detailed. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The following assigns the return value of **include()** to the variable **$eyecatcher**.

```
$eyecatcher = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $jpath_eyecatcher_path);
```

Because the include() was successful, it returns a boolean value of *true*, which is presented as "1" when you echo it.

If you wish to load the **$eyecatcher** variable with the contents of the file as a string, you do:

```
$eyecatcher = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $jpath_eyecatcher_path);
```