# How to get the value from include statement in a variable?

Tags: php

Suppose I write a line

```
include Yii::app()->basepath.'/views/email/email_friend.php';
```

now how can i take the response of this line into a variable?

like

```
$abc = include Yii::app()->basepath.'/views/email/email_friend.php';
```

Comment: Try file_get_contents instead of include

Comment: `include` isn't a function, and (usually) has no return value. you can't do that. you could use OB, e.g. `ob_start(); include ...; $abc = ob_get_clean()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [require/include into variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948395/require-include-into-variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the PHP docs for include http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Example #5 is I think what you're looking for

```
return.php
<?php

$var = 'PHP';

return $var;

?>

noreturn.php
<?php

$var = 'PHP';

?>

testreturns.php
<?php

$foo = include 'return.php';

echo $foo; // prints 'PHP'

$bar = include 'noreturn.php';

echo $bar; // prints 1

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is the included file had a return with the desired value. It's been quite popular for some time.

so the include.php should like the following:

```
<?php
return ' World!';
```

and the including one:

```
<?php
$a = include('include.php');

echo 'Hello'.$a; // Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0):

When you include it's like you're copy/pasting the code into your PHP. If it's just inline PHP and there was a variable $abc in the include file 'email_friend.php' then you could access the variable normally after the include.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post. I hope my answer will be useful to someone. I combined the [Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5948404/601770) with the answer ["PHP/7 you can use a self-invoking anonymous function..."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41568962/601770)

```php
    define( 'WPPATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/public/partials/bla-bla.php' );
    $publicDisplayContent = (function () {
      // [PHP/7 you can use a self-invoking anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41568962/601770)
      // https://stackoverflow.com/a/5948404/601770
      ob_start();
      require_once(WPPATH);
      return ob_get_clean();  
    })(); // PHP/7 you can use a self-invoking anonymous function
    error_log( 'activate() >> $publicDisplayContent: ' . print_r( $publicDisplayContent, true ) ); 

       DOT DOT DOT

    'post_content'  => $publicDisplayContent,
```