# how to add/include add theme funtion.php file?

Tags: php, include

ı want to add following code between  < div >here < /div >  tags

for example:

```
$ad_code = '<div>include 'ban.php'; </div>';
```

but it doesn't work how can I do this

Comment: I don't get what You want, here You have article with description how ask good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry little english, my problem

div
between

I want to show paragraph banner in themes function.php file

I can not use php with code blog.

The part of code I want to add to php
sample:

include 'ban.php';

Comment: Is your problem actually about the inclusion of single quotation marks within a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [require/include into variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948395/require-include-into-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me assume ban.php

```
<?php
echo '<div>Banner</div>';
?>
```

and on your php file.

```
<?php
ob_start();
include('./ban.php');
$ad_code = ob_get_clean();
echo $ad_code;
?>
```

I think this is what you want, if i had understood your question correctly.

or try this

```
<?php
$ad_code = file_get_contents('./ban.php');
?>
```

Comment: my themes add :
https://gist.github.com/GaryJones/5259147

but my add. ban php??
I want to add 
include 'ban.php';  // Works.

Comment: It doesn't seems to work properly because it shows ban.php code too

Comment: ban.php
It shows all the codes in it.
I just want the banner, bring the banner codes to the screen

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div>
   <?php include ban.php; ?>
   </div>
```

It's really incredibly easy, and I can't believe Google could not have solved your problem here.

This is on the presumption you're putting this straight onto the page. It's hard to answer really as you've given us almost nothing to go on.

Following a little more info, this is a possible duplicate of; [require/include into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948395/require-include-into-variable)

Comment: thank you but , Banner does not appear

$ad_code = '<div><?php include ban.php; ?></div>';